# Creating an empty Controller breaks my magic model hook

Tags: ember.js

I have a template where I display information about my model.

Everything works great and it's all done by Ember. The model hook and `setupController` are done automatically since I use a route with a `model_id` parameter. I don't set them manually anywhere.

I wanted to add something, and the first thing I did was to create an empty controller. I wanted to eventually add some properties to it.

Let's say I have `templates/model/view.hbs`, I created `controllers/model/view.js`.

It's an empty controller. This is the content of the file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

When I run my app, the template appears, but it's empty. It's not a blank page, it's just that what I'm printing from the model doesn't show up.

When I delete the file, everything comes back to normal.

How come an empty controller can break my app like that? I tried creating a route file and set the model and setupController manually, but that doesn't work either.

I use ember-cli and Ember 1.10. The controller is created through ember-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what type of object the model is. Is this an array of models or a single model? What does your template look like? Does it reference them using model.foo or just foo?

Comment: It is a single model. Just foo, not model.foo. But I tried with model.foo, and it works! I'm curious to know why. Do you know?

Comment: The old behavior in ember (now deprecated) is to take your model and "proxy" it up using Ember.ObjectController (instead of Ember.Controller) so you adding your own would also be fine if you made it an ObjectController but I'd avoid that going forward if you can by using model.propertyNameWhatever in your templates :)